# UIImagePickerController memory leak on iOS5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

i am using UIImagePickerController in my application developing on iOS5 & XCode4.2, getting memory leak and i don't have any idea why i am getting this leak can you please give me the answer for this.

[image: here i am attaching my screen shot:]

and my code:

```
-(void)createImagePicker 
{
_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

_picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;

_picker.allowsEditing = YES;
_picker.showsCameraControls = NO;


_picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear; 

_picker.delegate = self;
_picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

}
```

and viewWillApper method:

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closeCameraButton:) name:@"ShowMainView" object:nil];
    [self createImagePicker];
    [m_cameraOverlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self presentModalViewController:_picker animated:NO];
    _picker.cameraOverlayView = m_cameraOverlayView;

    [cameraImgView setHidden:YES];
    [filterView setHidden:YES];
    m_cameraOverlayView.hidden = NO;
    cameraSelectedButton.hidden = NO;
    cancelButton.hidden = YES;
    selectButton.hidden = YES;

    for (id Object in [scrollview subviews])
    {
        if([Object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [Object removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    [m_toolbarImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 427, 320, 55)];
    [cameraSelectedButton setFrame:CGRectMake(128, 432, 86, 44)];

    [m_cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 434, 82, 40)];
    [m_cancelButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [m_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-bar-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [m_cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:110/256.0 green:52/256.0 blue:28/256.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 434, 35, 35)];
    [selectButton setFrame:CGRectMake(184, 434, 35, 35)];

    }
```

Comment: If you actually post the method in question, rather than a screen grab, it might help! Particularly your `createImagePicker` method...

Comment: I assume at some point you call `[_picker release]`?

Comment: no...i implemented this in xcode 4.2 so i didn't call relese method

Comment: If it's ARC are you weak or strong linking?

Comment: @lxt can you please tell me in brief

Comment: @laxcha imagepickercreates alots of issues in ios 5.Because whenever  memory leak it calls its viewdidload and viewwillappear which allocates all memory again. better option in use camera overlay

Comment: You should remove The Observer inside `viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ShowMainView" object:nil];`

Comment: Its August 2012 and I'm still experiencing this problem

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a problem with UIImagePickerController in iOS 5 whether using ARC or not.

I have an app developed for iOS 4 using xcode 3.2.5 and Instruments shows no leaks when a photo is either taken or selected from the library (tested on a device running iOS 4.1). The same code tested on a device running iOS 5.1 leaks as described.

I know this isn't an answer but the problem seems broader than the original question.

Comment: The memory leak in UIImagePickerController seems to occur while scrolling to select a photo. If you select a photo without scrolling, the leak doesn't happen. But if you scroll the photos (assuming you have enough photos to scroll), the leak occurs even if you don't select a photo, which rules out the problem being my code.

Answer (score 3):

Just saw that even the source code from apple linked [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/MyViewController_m.html) leaks with the same problem we have...

Answer (score 2):

You should call `[_picker release];` to relinquish ownership of _picker memory as described in the Apple Memory Management Docs.

Comment: The question is with ARC turned ON. Thus `release` cannot be called.

Comment: @edo42 yes as tikkes said this is in iOS5 so i can't call release

Comment: He didn't specify that ARC was ON

Answer (score 1):

I read many other posts about that issue. Someone says that it's an Apple problem, and that's why Zillian suggested that the PhotoPicker example also leaks. The workaround is to create only one instance of UIImagePickerController, probably as a singleton, and to never release it (or let ARC release it for you). In that way you will be using always the same instance and it will probably leak less times.

Comment: I tried this but that too did not work. It will still leak in the exact same way. Some people suggested some other things on [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752917/memory-leak-on-presentmodalviewcontroller) but none of them seemed to work for me. I would like to fix this but so far I didn't have any luck doing so.

Comment: I haven't said that the leak will go away, only try to reduce it. It isn't a great problem to have a leak in you app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running that app on the simulator? If so, it's a long history problem(or may come back):

> The leaks are mostly (but not entirely) on the simulator, and not
>   present on device.

http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2008/11/12/memory-usage-in-uiimagepickercontroller/