# Memory leak on presentModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm opening a camera for the user to take a picture.
I keep getting a memory leak when I took a picture and pressed "use" on:
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES],

Full code:

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;      
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                              (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; //This leaks
```

In both `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and `imagePickerControllerDidCancel` I put this line:

```
[imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I do know this question has been asked before but none of them seen to help me any further with the leak I have got.

Comment: ARC or manual memory management?

Comment: I do use ARC. Not manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in the code of iOS itself.

I downloaded the sample code of the Apple Developer Website and the same leak turned up. 
So this will be nothing I can fix myself and I hope this gets corrected soon.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug in iOS? Or is Apple's example code just wrong as well?

Comment: Since even a singleton of the UIImagePickerController won't help and still leaks memory I am quite convinced that this is a bug in iOS itself rather then in the example code.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not an ARC env:

Your 
`imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];` 
returns retain count +1,

then 
`[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]` 
retains your controller, so retain count +2,

on `[imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` 
it's +1, so you still have your controller hanging in memory.

Release your controller after `presentModalViewController`.

Comment: I am using ARC. Is there a way to solve this leak while using ARC?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

And get sure what you have

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// your code

[pool release];
```

Comment: I'm working in iOS 5.1 so this is not allowed if ARC is turned ON

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a `@property` for `imagePicker` and assigning:

```
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

Comment: I did try this but it still leaks in exactly the same way.