# Using Instruments to trace memory leak Xcode5 and iOS7

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, camera, automatic-ref-counting, calayer

I developed my first app and still learning. Just updated Xcode 5 yesterday and my iPhone 5 is running iOS 7.1. I am now working on understanding the Instruments tool to analyze my app. I am using the Leak profile in Instruments and have come across a retain cycle and leak which I can't figure out. Appreciate any help I can get to understand a) how to pinpoint the bug and b) what I did wrong and how to avoid it in the future.

In my app, I am using the camera to take a pic. While the camera is up, I tapped on the screen to focus and that is when I noticed the leak pop up in Instruments. Looks like there is a retain cycle not in my code (if I understand correctly) and a root leak in my code which I don't understand.

I am using **ARC**, so I should not have to release "picker" in the part of my code that Instruments is pointing me to (part 2 below, with code).

[image: CALayer Retain Cycle]

1. What can I do about the retain cycle. It is not in my code, but am I still the cause of it? Does it stem from the "root leak?" If I am NOT responsible for it, what's should I do about it?

[image: Root Leak]

2. My only code in this stack trace does not help me understand where the leak is coming from. The line is Instruments points me to in my code is [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; in my imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method. I am pasting the code below.

> ```
>  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
>     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
> {
>     UIImage *pickerImage = [info objectForKey:
>                             UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
>
>     _imageView.image = pickerImage;
>
>     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // <--- mem-leak
> }
> ```

**EDIT** - Code where I create my UIImagePickerController.

> ```
> - (IBAction)snapPicture:(id)sender
> {
>     UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
>
>     // If the camera button was tapped AND we have a camera, use it...
>     if ((sender == _cameraButton) && [UIImagePickerController
>          isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
>     {
>         [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
>     } else {
>         [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
>     }
>
>     imagePicker.delegate = self;
>
>     // bring up the image picker view
>     [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: So what's a CAMBlurredSnapshotView? I mean, this is apparently the cause of the problem. Is this code you took from somewhere else?

Comment: @Austin - could not figure out how to make a code block here. You can see the method where I create the UIImagePickerController here: http://pastebin.com/7s37iaFA

Comment: @matt - I am not using any other code here. I do use GKImagePicker for cropping the pic, but that code is not called here. I assumed CAMBlurredSnapshotView was part of Apple's camera API.

Comment: Good answer. So good, in fact, that I am now convinced that there is nothing you can or should do about this leak. It is, as you say, built-in.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple about this and it immediately came back as a duplicate. So, they know about it; that doesn't mean they'll fix it any time soon, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my theory: what you've encountered is evidently a bug (or flaw) in Apple's own code, and all you can do is laugh maniacally and forget about it.

To test my theory, I ran my own code, written totally separately and at a different time. It does almost the same thing your code does: it lets the user take a picture, and puts the image into the interface. Here's my code:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch17p702takeAPicture/ch30p962takeAPicture/ViewController.m

I ran my code under Instruments with the Leaks instrument, and guess what? I saw the same issues you did.

[image]

Naturally, I then started searching on Stack Overflow, and all of this turns out to be old ground. For example:

[UIImagePickerController memory leak on iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718257/uiimagepickercontroller-memory-leak-on-ios5)

Even Apple's own sample code, called PhotoPicker (or Using UIImagePickerController to Select Pictures and Take Photos) has the same leak.

Comment: Thank you all. Should've included UIImagePickerController in my search. I was including CALayer and found others that didn't answer this problem. Appreciate your time and effort. I had just fixed a different memory leak where I had to release a CFTypeRef and was not aware of that until today. So I was thinking maybe there was something I didn't understand about the image picker that I was missing. Thanks again!

Comment: Here's the discussion of CFTypeRef memory management in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_cftyperefs

Comment: @matt : So are there any solutions of it? Anyone report bug to apple? I run "SquareCam" demo application it also crashed some times after.My app is also crashing after few mins...

Comment: @San Of course I did report it, esp. since the bug is demonstrable with Apple's own code. My advice would be to try iOS 8. If it isn't fixed there, file another bug report for sure! — BTW, never ask "Anyone report?" Just report! Don't let others do your work for you, and besides, the more reports the better (i.e. never hold back from reporting just because someone else has reported); Apple treats reports as votes.

Comment: @Matt thanks. I was trying with IOS8 but there are more other issues with CFNetwork. I am not able to run the my app. I have one curiosity how other apps are working properly like snapchat? Are they doing something different?